# Empty space check and string.split error

Tags: python, string

I have the following error when I try to split a string into two values.

> Error: builtins.ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

When I debug, it shows that the first `if` statement is still true, even when there is no space in the string. I am wondering why is it not going into the second `if` statement.

```
if ('' in line):        
    line=line.strip('\n')
    code,number=line.split()
    print(code,number)
if '' not in line:
    print('missing key')
```

Comment: In the text file there are no empty strings , rather there are strings without spaces. So I was wondering why is it not working in that case? Also could you please tell me how to determine if you have two items? Thanks

Comment: "In the text file there are not empty strings" - that does not make sense and is not what @Shashank is saying. In Python, every string is considered to contain the empty string. Therefore, if you search for the empty string, you will always find it. He goes on to clarify that `''` and `' '` - the empty string and a string containing exactly one space character - are different.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Made sense.  Thank you a lot. Made a lot more sense!

Comment: Just edited your question a bit and occurred to me that some sample input would be a great addition to this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'' in anystring` will always be `True` because it's the empty string. The empty string is always going to be in every single possible string, just like the empty set is a subset of every set. You probably mean to check for `' '` which is a single space character.

A better approach would be to split the string on whitespace and check the length of the list to determine if you have two items. For example:

```
linesplit = line.split()
if len(linesplit) == 2:
    code, number = linesplit
    print(code, number)
else:
    print('missing key')
```

This is the method where you look before you leap [(LBYL)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl).

```
try:
    code, number = line.split()
    print(code, number)
except ValueError:
    print('missing key')
```

And this is an alternative method where you ask for forgiveness rather than permission [(EAFP)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp).

By the way, I took out the calls to `str.strip`, because using `str.split` takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

`''` is the empty string. Asking `'' in line` is like asking whether you can make room in your daily schedule for something that takes zero time. Of course you can. Always. Ask `' ' in line` instead.

Answer (score -1):

1. use else: instead of second if.
2. `if ('' in line):` should be `if '' in line:`

Comment: `if '' in line` will always evaluate to `True` and is therefore neither a useful statement nor the answer to this question.